# Count concatenated values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm generating a query where I'm getting list of userid's seprated by comma using `GROUP_CONCAT`. I want to count these IDs in the same query. Can I do so?

```
$query="SELECT id, 
            longitude, 
            latitude, 
            game_date, 
            min_player, 
            game_description, 
            is_public, 
            is_user_coming, 
            allow_player_invite, 
            location, 
            game_type, 
            game_status, 
            cdate, 
            ownerid, 
            COUNT(j.users) as joinees,
            users.username
            FROM games 
            left join 
            (SELECT gameid, GROUP_CONCAT(userid, ',') as users 
            from user_game_join where games.id=user_game_join.gameid) j on j.gameid=id 
            join (select id as uid,name as username from users) users on users.uid=ownerid 
            AND (`location` LIKE '$location%' or `location` LIKE '".ucfirst($location)."%')";
```

This is my query and I need to get the number of joineers. Attached herewith is the snapshot of my tables:
[image: user_game_join]

[image: games]

[image: users]

Comment: Maybe don't use GROUP_CONCAT() ?

Comment: Suggest a better way then!

Comment: We prefer sqlfiddles to snapshots! (well, I do)

Comment: Yeah, but I was in a hurry. Got the solution anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me with that. Surprisingly, I was using `join` in wrong place. Sharing the query just in case someone might find it helpful:

```
SELECT games.*,ugj.joinees,u.username FROM games JOIN 
(select id as uid, name as username from users) users on users.uid = games.ownerid 
AND games.id='$gid' left join 
(select count(userid) as joinees,gameid as gid from user_game_join group by gameid ) ugj on games.id=ugj.gid LEFT JOIN 
(select id,name as username from users) u on u.id=games.ownerid
```

Comment: This query is a mess. Publishing it could help no one. What is the point of that first JOIN, and there appears to be no need for any subqueries at all!

Comment: Well, depends on scenario. I cannot explain everything to you that I had over here. If you think it's worthless, fine, who gives a damn!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT gameid, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(userid, ',') as users,
       count(userid) as user_count
from user_game_join 
where games.id = user_game_join.gameid
```

Comment: that gives me 0 as result while I can clearly see in table the count is 1!

Comment: Then add your query, table structure and example data to your question.